# jQuery: How to capture the TAB keypress within a Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to capture the TAB keypress, cancel the default action and call my own javascript function.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

**Edit:** Since your element is dynamically inserted, you have to use [delegated `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as in your example, but you should bind it to the keydown event, because as @Marc comments, in IE the keypress event doesn't capture non-character keys:

```
$("#parentOfTextbox").on('keydown', '#textbox', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // call custom function here
  } 
});
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/amoci/123/).

Comment: when I push TAB in IE6+ the event does not fire (it fires on any alphanumeric key though)... I need to use .live('keypress', fn)

Comment: If only works with live, maybe you are inserting your textbox element dynamically, if the element is already on the page, it will work, check this example: http://jsbin.com/oguhe

Comment: yea the textbox is dynamically inserted. my example with id #textbox was just to simplify the question =)

Comment: @Jon, the reason you aren't using $(selector).live("keydown", fn) is ?  CMS is suggesting using keydown because in IE, keypress does not work for noncharacter keys, (such as Tab)

Comment: keydown does not work in Opera. You have to use: $('textarea').bind($.browser.opera ? 'keypress' : 'keydown', function() {});

Comment: @AppleGrew: it says so, yes, but it's not true - at least for keypress. For Tab e.which is 0 and e.keyCode is 9 (as it should be). Tested in FF 3.5.16, jQuery 1.6.2.

Comment: I suggest delegated event rather than live, live can be very slow

Comment: live is depreciated in newer jquery versions and you should not use it. If you were to stumble on this then use the other answer using `.on`

Comment: a good example for TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and ENTER key is here http://jsbin.com/fecoyefaho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: plus one for var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

Answer (score 22):

Working example in jQuery 1.9:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '#textbox', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do your code
    }
});
```

Comment: make `e.preventDefault();` double to prevent inserting whitespace into textbox.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#textbox').live('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do work
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, to cancel the default action, use e.preventDefault(); in the first line of the function.

Comment: @Jon, keypress doesn't capture noncharacter keys in IE

Comment: @Marc I see that, how can I be compatible with IE and FF?

Comment: ^^ The irony... jQuery is supposed to bridge the gap between broswers, so that you don't have to worry about stuff like this.

Comment: @Jagd, jQuery can't infer intent.  keypress and keydown are not equivalent for good reason.  It just so happens, this situation does not require the distinction.

Answer (score 7):

**Above shown methods did not work for me, may be i am using bit old jquery, then finally the below shown code snippet works for - posting just in case somebody in my same position**

```
$('#textBox').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('tab');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

An important part of using a key down on tab is knowing that tab will always try to do something already, don't forget to "return false" at the end.

Here is what I did. I have a function that runs on .blur and a function that swaps where my form focus is. Basically it adds an input to the end of the form and goes there while running calculations on blur.

```
$(this).children('input[type=text]').blur(timeEntered).keydown(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == "9") {
            window.tabPressed = true;
            // Here is the external function you want to call, let your external
            // function handle all your custom code, then return false to
            // prevent the tab button from doing whatever it would naturally do.
            focusShift($(this));
            return false;
        } else {
            window.tabPressed = false;
        }
        // This is the code i want to execute, it might be different than yours
        function focusShift(trigger) {
            var focalPoint = false;
            if (tabPressed == true) {
                console.log($(trigger).parents("td").next("td"));
                focalPoint = $(trigger).parents("td").next("td");

            }
            if (focalPoint) {
                $(focalPoint).trigger("click");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#contra').focusout(function (){
    $('#btnPassword').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Suppose you have TextBox with Id txtName*

```
$("[id*=txtName]").on('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 9) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('Tab Pressed');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture an event tab using [this](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) JQuery API.

```
$( "#yourInputTextId" ).keydown(function(evt) {
   if(evt.key === "Tab")
      //call your function
});
```

Comment: it works for me after adding evt.preventDefault(); in the if

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

`$("[id*=txtName]").on('keydown', function(e) { var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; if (keyCode == 9) { e.preventDefault(); alert('Tab Pressed'); } });`