# HTML form, make tab key trigger indent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The default behaviour in browsers is to select the next form element. I want my textbox to indent code by, lets say 4 spaces when tab is pressed. Just like if you were indenting code in an IDE. How would I achieve this behaviour in JavaScript? If I have to use jQuery, or its easier, I'm fine with that.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea

Comment: If you are trying to make an editor you should take a look at [ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking the key code and adding 4 spaces to the element should do it.  You can prevent the default when the tab key is pressed.  Like so?:

*Edit after all comments:*

Ahh, ok so you're actually asking for several JS functions (get cursor position in text area, change text, set cursor position in text area).  A little more looking around would have given you all of these, but since I'm a nice guy I'll put it in there for ya.  The other answers can be found in [this post about getCursorPosition()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea) and [this post about setCursorPosition()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area).  I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FufNy/5/) for ya.  Here's the code update

```
<script>

    $('#myarea').on('keydown', function(e) { 
    var thecode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

    if (thecode == 9) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var html = $('#myarea').val();
        var pos = $('#myarea').getCursorPosition(); // get cursor position
        var prepend = html.substring(0,pos);
        var append = html.replace(prepend,'');
        var newVal = prepend+'    '+append;
        $('#myarea').val(newVal);
        $('#myarea').setCursorPosition(pos+4);
    } 
});

new function($) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var pos = 0;
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        // Firefox support
        else if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart == '0')
            pos = el.selectionStart;

        return pos;
    }
} (jQuery);

new function($) {
  $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
    if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
      $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
      var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  }
}(jQuery);
​
</script>

<textarea id="myarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: It is assuming the tab has been used at the end of the field. Could you supply us with up-to-date jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Fike: Yes, `.live()` is deprecated since jQuery ~1.4.2 in favour of `.delegate()`. Since jQuery 1.7 both are deprecated in favour of `.on()`.

Comment: @Fike: Give me the link, I will investigate that.

Comment: Good call, I changed to .on() for ya.  Also, I realized that it should use .val() instead of .html() since it is a form element.  I just tried it out and it works well!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't select jQuery as the framework. Works nicely :)

Comment: @Fike: It works only when editing at the end, as I said above. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/FufNy/

Comment: @Tadeck oh.. Well thats not much use to me then.

Comment: @Fike: I know. Maybe iDsteven may improve it to work correctly when editing.

Comment: Just edited, you needed more code than you let on, lucky I'm bored today!