# Change default tab function on a website

Tags: javascript, css, html

For every web browser, pressing the `Tab` key cycles through selecting the various input elements / links etc. on the page. I want to make it so that when a user presses `Tab` in a`<textarea>`, it creates a "tab" character like in a text document. How can that be done?

Comment: As explained by **@Dano** this can be done. However, it is almost always a bad idea to surprise the user by changing default behaviours. Think long and hard about whether you **should** be doing this before you work out **how** to do it. You will provide a User eXperience that drives away people who expect your site to follow web conventions and use default behaviours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637396/7028020). Basically you catch the keypress, prevent default behaviour and indent you textarea instead. For an example, please check out the provided link.