# How to achieve normal Tab behaviour in a Vaadin TextArea

Tags: vaadin

I am using Vaadin and I have a `TextArea`, and I want the user to be able to enter Tabs into the text. But pressing tab cycles through components in a web browser. Is there any configuration I can do to achieve this so that instead of cycling the user to the next component, a literal of `"\t"` is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vaadin TextArea is a simple HTML `<textarea>` element, which doesn't support the input of tab characters out of the box without client-side modifications. The tab character is usually used to switch focusable elements (tabindex).

You could use e.g. CodeMirror (https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/v-codemirror) to enable a client-side code editor which can handle tab characters. A second option is to extend the Vaadin TextArea with client-side JS/GWT extensions: see [Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea) and https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html

Comment: Thanks appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a shortcutlistener seems to work, e.g:

```
TextArea area = new TextArea("test")
area.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("Shortcut Name", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB, null) {
@Override
public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
    area.setValue(area.getValue() + "\t")
}
});
```