# Inserting an &emsp; into a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

### My Problem

I'm trying to insert a tab (`&emsp;`) into a `contenteditable` td. I've got it working a bit, but it's not going where I want it to go (on cursor). It's also preventing me from tabbing again unless I click in the window.

### Desired result

Tabbing should insert a tab `&emsp;` at the cursor location. I should also be able to continue tabbing as well as deleting any selections and replacing it with the tab `&esmp;`

### Code

JSfiddle works better: https://jsfiddle.net/0qz8td9y/2/

```js
function insertTab () {
  if (event.which === 9)
  {
      event.preventDefault()
      let selection = window.getSelection()
      let text = selection.anchorNode.data
      let start = selection.anchorOffset
      let end = selection.focusOffset
      let td = selection.anchorNode.parentNode
      let remove = end - start

      console.log(text + "hi")
      console.log(selection)
      text = text.split()
      text.splice(start, remove, "&emsp;")
      text = text.join("")
      console.log(text)
      td.innerHTML = text;
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="insertTab(event)">
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea)

Comment: First of all, you don't pass the Event Object into your function.