# Support tabs for indentation in <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am aware this question has been asked before ([Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea)), but the answers provided did not fix my problem. My code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  document.getElementById('input').onkeydown = e => {
    if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var s = this.selectionStart;
      this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + "\t" + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd);
      this.selectionEnd = s + 1;
    }
  }

  /* This jQuery solution doesn't work, either
            $('#input').keydown(e => {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    
                if (keyCode == 9) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var start = this.selectionStart;
                    var end = this.selectionEnd;
    
                    // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                                + "\t"
                                + $(this).val().substring(end));
    
                    // put caret at right position again
                    this.selectionStart =
                    this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
                }
            });
            */
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Browser is Google Chrome 67 on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solely caused by your use of arrow functions, which are affecting the scope the logic runs under. Hence `this` is the `window`, not the `textarea` which raised the event. Use traditional anonymous functions and your code works fine - and is also now supported by all versions of IE.

Also note that as you're using jQuery already you may as well use it to attach unobtrusive event handlers and for its succinct methods for amending form control values. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var s = this.selectionStart;
      $(this).val(function(i, v) {
        return v.substring(0, s) + "\t" + v.substring(this.selectionEnd)
      });
      this.selectionEnd = s + 1;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can the indent width be changed? Although StackOverflow's "run code snippet" displays a width of 4, it has a width of 8 when I actually run the code. Edit: Replacing `"\t"` with 4 spaces didn't work.

Comment: Sure, you could insert N number of spaces instead of a single tab.

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: I see no edits...?

Comment: I added "Replacing `"\t"` with 4 spaces didn't work" to the comment above. Anyway, only a single space is added to the textarea instead of 4.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about it then, as the issue your original question was about (the code not working at all) has been solved.