# Can you press tab in a textarea without changing focus while still typing?

Tags: javascript, html, input, event-listener

HTML:

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Are you able to still write a tab without unfocusing the textarea?

Comment: isn't your code working?

Comment: Just tried the code and it works.

Comment: Do you just want to know whether your code will work, or does it not work for you in some way?

Comment: Everyone look at the last sentence. I think the OP wants a tab (n-spaces), like writing in a text document.

Comment: "Are you able to still write a tab without unfocusing the textarea?" Well that is a strange question to ask. Did you try the code and see what happens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces to the end when tab is hit:

```
document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('#text').value += "    ";
    }
});
```

---

**Edit**: Worked on inserting spaces and I think this works:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

```
document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var ele = document.querySelector('#text');
        var caretPos = ele.selectionStart;
        var textAreaTxt = ele.value;
        var txtToAdd = "    ";
        ele.value = textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) 
                    + txtToAdd 
                    + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos);
        ele.selectionStart = caretPos + 4;
        ele.selectionEnd = caretPos + 4;
    }
});
```

With help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15977052/1171702 and a general search for `js add spaces at cursor position`.

Comment: and what if the cursor is not at the end?

Comment: touche! that's a problem. not sure how to find the cursor off the top of my head. anyone? Edit: did a quick search and this has been asked before, more or less. -- get the cursor position, cut/save the text from there to the end, add spaces, replace the text.

Comment: +1 fyi, [`document.execCommand.insertText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) would let you avoid all the `element.selectionStart` and `element.selectionEnd` shenanigans, except that firefox doesn't currently support it on form elements ([firefox bug 1220696](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696)).