# How can I insert TAB to indent code from textarea

Tags: javascript, key, textarea

I want that when TAB was pressed, the code will be indented. [I tried using these functions from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea).

Nothing works because I have 3 textareas.

```js
const htmlField = document.getElementById("html");
const cssField = document.getElementById("css");
const jsField = document.getElementById("js");
```

One next to the other. When I press TAB, the textarea beside is selected and nothing happens in the original source textarea from the event.

Comment: Try providing your html (is this for an html ui?) You example looks very incomplete are you. sure it's all there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link you provided, I have tested one of the answers and it seems to be working as intended. You just have to provide a closing `</textarea>` tag to each of your textareas.

```html
<textarea id="html" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;return false;}"></textarea>

<textarea id="css" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;return false;}"></textarea>

<textarea id="js" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;return false;}"></textarea>
```