# Disable tabbing out of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a little editor in react but in `textarea` I don't want the tab button to switch to the next field.

I tried a few variations of

```
<textarea className={style.textarea}
    required
    tabIndex="-1"
    type="text"
    value={text}
    onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
/>
```

without any luck. For example, I used `tabindex="-1"` as well
without any luck. For example, I used `tabIndex="-1"` as using an integer -1` but that also didn't work.

The desired behavior is that when I press `Tab` that it'd put a literal tab in my `textarea` instead of switching focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `onchange` [won't be effective for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection) as it only fires when focus leaves the textarea. Additionally `onkeyup` wouldn't be a great solve here because for accessibility reasons you want to allow users to tab into the textarea but then have tab perform a different function when focus is inside it.

Something like this may do the trick:

```js
function handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.key == "Tab") {
    e.preventDefault();

    const start = this.selectionStart;
    const end = this.selectionEnd;

    this.value =
      this.value.substring(0, start) + "\t" + this.value.substring(end);

    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea onkeydown="handleKeyDown.call(this, event)"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `tabIndex` accepts `number` as a parameter.
   In react, the correct way to pass in a number to an attribute is by wrapping it in curly braces `{ }`.
   This is how you should do this.
2. attribute `type` does not exist on `textarea`

```js
<textarea className={style.textarea}
    required
    tabIndex={-1}
    value={text}
    onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
/>
```