# How to insert a character(s) when another character is typed

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a plain HTML textarea. What I want to do is I want to be able to insert a different character when a character is typed. For example, I want to insert `<>` when `<` is typed into the textarea. Also, I want to be able to move the cursor between the `<` and `>` if possible.

Here's what I have for now. It only works if the cursor is at the end though.

```js
let editing = document.querySelector("#editing");

const handler = (event) => {
  if (editing.value.endsWith("<")) {
    editing.value += ">";
    editing.setSelectionRange(editing.selectionStart - 1, editing.selectionStart - 1)
  }
}

editing.addEventListener("propertychange", handler)
editing.addEventListener("input", handler)
```

```html
<textarea name="editing" id="editing"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for [How to get the caret column (not pixels) position in a textarea, in characters, from the start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-the-caret-column-not-pixels-position-in-a-textarea-in-characters)

Comment: @CharlesBamford It kind of does, I'll see

Comment: `event.data` has the info you're looking for, look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) for docs. Also use `event.target` instead of `editing`, it'll make your handler reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea) for very related discussion, which this answer is based on.

The following code should do what you want, by capturing the `keydown` event for `<` and replacing it with the insertion of `<>` (overwriting whatever the current selection is) and moving the cursor after the `<`:

```js
const editing = document.querySelector("#editing");

editing.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === '<') {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pos = editing.selectionStart;
    editing.value = editing.value.slice(0, pos) + '<>' +
      editing.value.slice(editing.selectionEnd);
    editing.selectionStart = editing.selectionEnd = pos + 1;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this approach also trashes the undo stack of the editor.  On Chrome, you can use `document.execCommand('insertText', false, '<>')` to simulate typing `<>`.  Unfortunately, this is not supported on Firefox, so it's not a great solution.

Comment: Wow that note about the undo stack lead me down a whole rabbit hole about preserving the undo stack. Supposedly, `execCommand` should be fixed in firefox 89 if [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#browser_compatibility) is correct. I can't believe the only way to edit a `textarea` value without killing the undo stack is to rely on deprecated apis.