# <textarea>: ctrl + z breaks after changing the value content through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an HTML textarea that accepts `tab` key input using JavaScript.
When I searched for a solution on the web, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea), but after some fiddling, I found out that `ctrl+z` stops working after I hit `tab` key.

Doing some more experiments revealed that changing the value attribute was likely the culprit of this problem. Here is a small scale code example that you can hopefully reproduce this behavior yourself.
https://codepen.io/MartianLord/pen/gORKPGp?editors=1010
I managed to find a workaround using `document.execCommand` to simulate the user input, but this method is deprecated [as you can see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), so I am looking for a more up to date solution.

Comment: I've worked in a solution long ago building a textfield to past and copy piece of code. Instead of `<textarea>` i've used `contentEditable` property. You should look if it fit in your project.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Answer (score 4):

To support `ctrl+z` while using `tab` in `<textarea>`, you need to implement undo, redo functions to connect with `<textarea>`. When the `<textarea>` changes, record the changes in the history, and revert when `ctrl+z` key input occurs.

[UndoRedojs](https://github.com/iMrDJAi/UndoRedo.js) is a library for this task.

I think there will be a lot of work to be done, such as setting the selection position, in order to fully implement it. I recommend using a text editor that has already been created.