# dispatchEvent doesn't work for Enter > Tab simulation

Tags: javascript, dom, events

I want to fire a `Tab` keyboard event when `Enter` is pressed.

What am I doing wrong? I followed [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically).

```js
function enterToTab(e) {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
        console.log(e.key);
        e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "Tab" }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert a tab when someone presses enter?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this for an input or textarea? There are other ways to insert a tab instead of simulating a keypress.

Comment: I want to achieve the tab behavior somehow. My idea was to do it this way. I'd love to hear another approach.

Comment: You can take a page out of this book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea

Comment: It's more of the same explanation. I've read all of them, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be working, there has to be something special in your case.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("#main");

div.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Tab") {
    if (e.target.style.background === "lightblue") {
      e.target.style.background = "pink"
    } else {
      e.target.style.background = "lightblue"
    }
  }
})

function enterToTab(e) {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    div.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      key: "Tab"
    }));
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", enterToTab)
```

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> mouse click here then press Enter </div>
```