# Selector for tab-highlighted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is there a CSS or jQuery selector for the element which has received focus via the tab key, like you commonly do with anchor tags and form elements?

Comment: Does it have to be via the tab key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
if ($(".selector").is( ":focus" ))
{
    // Do something
}
```

If you want to highlight an element on focus use this:

```
$(".selector").focus(function()
{
    $(".selector").css("background-color","#FF99CC");
});
```

EDIT: @Musa brings up a good point. If it has to be triggered by tab then look at this post: [jQuery: How to capture the TAB keypress within a Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314450/jquery-how-to-capture-the-tab-keypress-within-a-textbox) I know it's for a textbox but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Yea but I like to extend sometimes if people aren't used to a language.

Comment: sure, it depends on the actual purpose. maybe CSS is enough, maybe Drew needs jQuery

Comment: I was really just curious about tab selection, but your answer made me think about what's actually going on there. +1.

Comment: Hey no problem that's what I'm here for!