# Contain tab key within a div or a modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, tabcontrol

I have an application built using angularjs. On one page i have a modal pop up with form elements(elements are not within a form tag consists of buttons and input tags). When the bootstrap  modal opens the focus is on the first input element. Is there a way by which i can contain the tab key press event only to the bootstrap modal pop up, cause when i press tab a few times more the control goes to the browser address bar and i can edit the URL. I do not want this behavior, the tab press should only allow users to have focus on the pop up window.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find your answer here

```
$('#confirmCopy :input:first').focus();

$('#confirmCopy :input:last').on('keydown', function (e) { 
    if ($("this:focus") && (e.which == 9)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#confirmCopy :input:first').focus();
    }
});
```

[Keep tabbing within modal pane only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593061/4578345)