# How to stop TAB key event from firing when a modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

When the modal is showing, how can I disable key events like TAB? I have multiple buttons and fields in a form on the page that can be selected (focused) by tabbing. I want to disable that when the modal is showing. The application uses Angular and the modal is in a child component.

```
<button tabindex="0">Button1</button>
<button tabindex="0">Button2</button>
<form>...</form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep tabbing within modal pane only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572084/keep-tabbing-within-modal-pane-only)

Comment: @Kos, I'm looking for an Angular typescript solution rather than javascript. So that might be different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this - use Renderer2 and listen for a keydown event and filter events by keyCode. Then on modal hide remove that listener.

```
onShow() {
   this.removeTabKeyListener = this.renderer.listen('document', 'keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 9) { 
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
}

onHide() {
  this.removeTabKeyListener();
}
```

A little example - http://plnkr.co/edit/LdpmCpgapPbrA26fGO9U?p=preview

Comment: How can I initialise the renderer in the component.ts?

Comment: add it in component's constructor, like I did in the example `constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}`

Comment: and don't forget to import it from `@angular/core` first

Comment: What type is removeTabKeyListener ? I got a `TypeError: this.removeTabKeyListener is not a function` when calling `onHide()`

Comment: It's a function. Did you follow the example I made below? http://plnkr.co/edit/LdpmCpgapPbrA26fGO9U?p=preview , file `events.ts`

Comment: I can't view the link - could you paste how you declared `removeTabKeyListener` in the component?

Comment: `removeTabKeyListener: Function;` If you can't use plunkr for some reason, here's a pastebin link with the code https://pastebin.com/9pviq3Bd

Comment: I created another question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385656/listener-is-not-a-function-error-when-trying-to-unbind-renderer-event-listener

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own event listener:

```
// Your event listener
function preventTab(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode === 9) { // If tab key is pressed
    e.preventDefault() // Stop event from its action
  }
}

// Call this when modal window opens
document.addEventListener(preventTab);

// Call this when modal window closes/unmounts
document.removeEventListener(preventTab);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Angular typescript?

Comment: Sure give me a second :)

Comment: Well the typescript code looks exactly like mine after conversion. I don't do angular or typescript but you should not worry about that. Important things are: 1) define the preventTab handler 2) `addEventListener` when you want to stop the tab key from working 3) `removeEventListener` when you want to make the tab work again

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tab by preventDafault the keyCode 9 (tab) on keydow:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Of course you'll want that on your modal opener and not as is, so it won't permanently disable tabs ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code it will just disable your tab key when modal is showing.

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which==9) // keycode for tab key
    {
        checkmodal = $('#myModal').is(':visible'); //check modal is opened or not
        if (checkmodal){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```