# Making background inert for CSS overlay

Tags: javascript, html, angular, css

I have a css overlay where the developer created a modal window

```
.modal__overlay {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Can I make background inert (tab should not work in background. It should only work in overlay screen)
This app is developed in angular 6

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, did you want the modal to block everything else? if so you could just throw a div behind the modal that's black to block access to other content.

Comment: In addition, here is an answer specifically for blocking tab events from reaching the background elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382618/how-to-stop-tab-key-event-from-firing-when-a-modal-is-open

Comment: I'm working on ADA compliance. So when modal window comes, if I press tab, the control goes to background screen. I want to block this and if modal window comes, the tab control should exists only in modal window